# Java library for Bayesian Networks

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, software, java

As the headline suggest, I am looking for a java library for learning and inference of Bayesian Networks. I have already found some, but I am hoping for a recommendation.

Requirements in a quick overview:

- written in Java (my overlord tells me that this is no point of discussion)
- configuration is possible via code (and not solely via a GUI).
- source code available
- project is still maintained
- the more powerful, the better

Which one do you recommend?

Comment: same reason as here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76869/is-there-an-implementation-of-item-item-collaborative-filtering-in-r

Answer (score 3):

You can easily accomplish this with R though rJava ([**JRI**](http://rosuda.org/JRI/), to be precise).  You should tell your overlord that you want to use the best tool for the job.

Comment: I'll try. Which R-package do you recommend ?

Answer (score 2):

See the [packages](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/overview-summary.html) of the open source project Weka, which is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks. The algorithms can either be applied directly to a dataset or called from your own Java code.

This is the class for [Bayes Network learning](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/bayes/BayesNet.html)

Comment: It seems that a disadvantage of this implementation is, that one cannot define a bn-architecture on his own.