# Software for learning Bayesian belief networks

Tags: bayesian, software

I am looking for an easy to use stand alone software that is able to construct [Bayesian belief networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) out of data. The software should (of course ;-) be free.

Can anybody recommend something? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/java-library-for-bayesian-networks

Comment: @steffen Yours is a very *similar* question, but it's not an **exact** duplicate.  You had several specific requirements unrelated to this question (e.g. that it uses Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own link contains a load of free tools (near the bottom: software resources), and you can check the bayesian task view at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 5):

[bnlearn](http://www.bnlearn.com/)  is a powerful `R` package for Bayesian networks with constraint and score-based structure learning algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

[SamIam](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/) could be what you are searching for. It features an easy to use GUI and is particularly useful for getting a "feel" for bayesian networks.

Answer (score 1):

[DMelt](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) includes Java classes for Bayesian networks. It is free software.